# Case condition in a where clause having another sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, jasper-reports, case

I'm working on a jasper report which takes one parameter based on which it should have a different where clause. Below is the query I'm using but seems there's a syntax error somewhere.

```
  select customer.name
         customer_order.name
  from customer, customer
  where customer.orders > 0
    and customer_order.customer_id = customer.id
    and customer_order.name in
        (
           case when (<paramter> = 1) then ('order1', 'order2')
           else  (select order_name from customer_order)
           end
         );
```

I appreciate any help,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically create any part of a query using parameter as placeholder .

1) Lets say you have a parameter param1 which is the actual parameter

2) Create another parameter say param2 which has the epression like 
    $P{param1}.longValue () == 1 
        ? " and field1=  " 
        : " and field1 = "

3) Use param2 as a placeholder in the query

```
    Select 
        blah blah
    From 
        blah blha
    Where
        blah blah
        $P!{param2}
```

Now , depending upon the param1 value you where clause may look like

```
        Where 
            blah blah
            and field1=  <exp1>
        or 

         Where 
            blah blah
            and field1=  <exp2>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't write the query like this.  Here is an alternative:

```
where . . .
      ((<parameter> = 1) and customer_order.name in ('order1', 'order2') or
       (<parameter> <> 1) and customer_order.name in (select order_name from customer_order)
      )
```

This is assuming that `<parameter>` is not NULL.  If that is allowed, you need to add this into the logic.